# Why i can't put the condition of 'elif' in same line of 'if' condition in this code?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Well I am trying to print alphabet "R" using for loop and if-else condition is i dont understand that why i have to use an elif statement as i couldn't run the code using only if statement.
if try to put the elif content in if it doesn't work.

```
a=4
b=2
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(5):
        if (j==0) or ((j==4)and (0<i<3)) or ((i==0 or i==3) and (4>j>0)) :
            print("R",end=" ")
        elif (i==a and j==b) and j>0:
            print("R",end=" ")
            a+=1
            b+=1
        else:
            print(" ",end=" ")
    print()
```

This code is working fine

```
a=4
b=2
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(5):
        if (j==0) or ((j==4)and (0<i<3)) or ((i==0 or i==3) and (4>j>0)) or ((i==a and j==b) and j>0):
            print("R",end=" ")
            a+=1
            b+=1
        else:
            print(" ",end=" ")
    print()
```

I cannot make R pattern with this code like below.

```
"""R R R R   
   R       R 
   R       R 
   R R R R   
   R   R     
   R     R   
   R       R """
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify what your issue is. It is unfortunately not clear just from an "English language" standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
a=4
b=2
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(5):
        if (j==0) or ((j==4)and (0<i<3)) or ((i==0 or i==3) and (4>j>0)) or ((i==a and j==b) and j>0):
            print("R",end=" ")
            # This part is edited.
            if (i==a and j==b) and j>0:
                a+=1
                b+=1
        else:
            print(" ",end=" ")
    print()
```

This part of the code:

```
a+=1
b+=1
```

Should be executed only when:

```
(i==a and j==b) and j>0
```

is True.

Comment: Thanks bro, but i was asking that why i cannot run the code in single line.  Reason?

Comment: @chulbulpanday He answered you, that this is because you do not want to promote `a` and `b` if the first condition is `True`, but only if the second condition is.